# Extract datetime components from a duration column with different formats

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time, tidyr

I have a small table like this, generated from slurm logs

| username | cpus | run_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2 | 1-15:02:41 |
| user1 | 4 | 12:37 |
| user2 | 48 | 2:05 |

I want to perform some operations on the run_time of the jobs per user.  To start I want to parse the `run_time` field into days, hours, minutes, and seconds.   To do this I am trying the `extract` command as below, but I can't figure out how to parse the optional days (the "1-" that only shows up in the first row.

Example command

```
R <- tribble(
    ~user,    ~cpus, ~run_time,
    "usr1",  2,     "1-15:02:41",   
    "user1", 4,    "12:37",   
    "user2", 48,    "2:05",    
)

R %>% extract(run_time, into=c("days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"), "([0-9]+)?-([0-9]+)?:([0-9]+):([0-9]+)")
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  user   cpus days  hours minutes seconds
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 usr1      2 1     15    02      41     
2 user1     4 NA    NA    NA      NA     
3 user2    48 NA    NA    NA      NA
```

is there something I can do to parse the `run_time` and have days and hours come up as "0" when they are missing from the `run_time`?

Answer (score 2):

`separate` is probably better here, with `fill = "left"`:

```r
R %>% 
  separate(run_time, into = c("days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"),
           fill = "left", convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 × 6
  user   cpus  days hours minutes seconds
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>
1 usr1      2     1    15       2      41
2 user1     4    NA    NA      12      37
3 user2    48    NA    NA       2       5
```

---

Or with the newer `separate_wider_delim`:

```r
R %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(run_time, delim = regex("\\W"), 
                       names = c("days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"),
                       too_few = "align_end")
```

Answer (score 2):

While I like the idea of using `fill = "left"`, it is prone to errors. Here, I make sure that every `run_time` has all four components (i.e. days, hours, minutes, and seconds) and then use `separate`; I also added a row to the dataset to show why we need to do this explicitly instead of just using `fill` argument.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~user,    ~cpus, ~run_time,
  "usr1",  2,     "1-15:02:41",   
  "user1", 4,    "12:37",   
  "user2", 48,    "2:05",
  "usr2", 20,    "2-2:05",
)


df1 %>% 
  mutate(run_time = ifelse(grepl("-", run_time), 
                                      run_time, paste0("0-", run_time)), 
         run_time = ifelse(grepl("\\d+-\\d+:\\d+:\\d+", run_time), 
                                      run_time, paste0(run_time, ":00"))) %>% 
  separate(run_time, into = c("days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"), convert = TRUE)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   user   cpus  days hours minutes seconds
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1 usr1      2     1    15       2      41
#> 2 user1     4     0    12      37       0
#> 3 user2    48     0     2       5       0
#> 4 usr2     20     2     2       5       0
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `lubridate`s time functions and `readr`s `parse_time`. Using `parse_time` to get a complete time stamp including seconds.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)

df %>% 
  mutate(days = as.numeric(sub("-*\\d+:.*", "", run_time)), 
         time = hms(parse_time(sub("^\\d+-", "", run_time))),
         days = replace(days, is.na(days), 0), 
         hours = hour(time), 
         minutes = minute(time), 
         seconds = second(time)) %>% 
  select(-time)
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  user   cpus run_time    days hours minutes seconds
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 usr1      2 1-15:02:41     1    15       2      41
2 user1     4 12:37          0    12      37       0
3 user2    48 2:05           0     2       5       0
```